# Python: How to filter dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I want to achieve the following, but using dictionary.

```
name_selected = "Jason"

if name_selected == "John":
    age = 10
    gender = "Male"
elif name_selected == "Jason":
    age = 20
    gender = "Male"

print(age, gender)
```

```
data = {"name": ["John", "Jason"],
         "age": [10, 20],
      "gender": ["Male", "Male"]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a poor data organization. It would be better if you made the names the dictionary keys:

```
data = {
    "John": { "age": 10, "gender": "Male"},
    "Jason": { "age": 20, "gender": "Male"}
}

age = data[name_selected]["age"]
gender = data[name_selected]["gender"]
```

But if you're stuck with your data structure, you can use `index()` to get the index in the `name` element, then use that to get the corresponding values in the other elements.

```
try:
    index = data['name'].index(name_selected)
    age = data['age'][index]
    gender = data['gender'][index]
except:
    print(f'{name_selected} not found')
```

Comment: Thank you for calling out the bad structure. I had a question with sticking to it or changing it.

Comment: @thebadgateway I don't think your caveat is necessary. The original `if` code also only supports one match of the name. This is equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're testing `name_selected == ...`, the possible values of `name_selected` are the dictionaries you want. Dictionaries are the structure that replaces `if-elif` lookup on a variable.

Given that, you can store the remaining data in any number of ways. Here's a tuple that you can unpack:

```
data = {'John': (10, 'Male'),
        'Jason': (20, 'Male')}
```

Then you can do

```
age, gender = data[name_selected]
```

You can extend the idea with another nested dictionary:

```
data = {'John': {
    'age': 10, 'gender': 'Male'},
        'Jason': {
    'age': 20, 'gender': 'Male'}
}
```

Now it might be better not to unpack:

```
person = data[name_selected]
# use person ['age'] and person['gender']
```

A more application-specific solution would be to make the values custom objects (like a `collections.namedtuple`) that would let you access the data for an individual as attributes.